# Google Sheets: Check if any values exist in another column for each row

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

I have a column list of "Priority" customers:

| Priority |
| --- |
| A |
| B |
| C |
| D |

Separately, I have a range of products that various customers buy.

| Product | Evaluate | Customer 1 | Customer 2 | ... | Customer n |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Drum | TRUE | C | S | ... |  |
| Bell | FALSE | T | U | ... | Z |
| Horn | TRUE | A |  | ... |  |

I would like to use an **ArrayFormula** to compute column "Evaluate" which checks whether a customer in column "Priority" exists for each row in range Customer 1 - Customer n.

Currently, I am using SEARCH for each row for each customer:

```
=IF(A2="","",IF(IFERROR(search('Priority'!$A$2,G2),0)
+IFERROR(search('Priority'!$A$3,G2),0)
+IFERROR(search('Priority'!$A$4,G2),0)
+IFERROR(search('Priority'!$A$5,G2),0)
...
```

Where G2 is a single cell in a row for my product table with comma-separated values for the customer (A, T, U...) and $A$3, $A$4, $A$5... are my priority customers in a separate column. I am dragging this formula down to evaluate each row. I'd like help coming up with a more efficient formula that doesn't require dragging down to the bottom (arrayformula would be ideal).

Hopefully that's clear - thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this (assuming your Priority column is on sheet Priority!A:A):

```
=arrayformula({"Evaluate";if(A2:A<>"",regexmatch(query(Priority!A2:A,"",9^9),regexreplace(trim(flatten(query(transpose(C2:E),"",9^9)))," ","|")),)})
```

[image]

Increase the range `D2:F` depending on how many customer columns you have.

The likelihood is that you'll have customer names with spaces so to avoid partial regex matches, you could try:

```
=arrayformula({"Evaluate";if(A2:A<>"",regexmatch(char(9998)&regexreplace(regexreplace(trim(query(regexreplace(Priority!A2:A," ",char(9999)),"",9^9))," ",char(9998)),char(9999)," ")&char(9998),char(9998)&regexreplace(regexreplace(trim(flatten(query(transpose(regexreplace(C2:E," ",char(9999))),"",9^9)))," ",char(9998)&"|"&char(9998)),char(9999)," ")&char(9998)),)})
```

[image]

Comment: This is perfect. What I have in reality is a single column "Customer" which has a comma-separated list of customers (A, B, C, D) for each row . I replaced "C2:F" in your formula with ArrayFormula(IFERROR(SPLIT(C2:C,","))) (with column C being my customer column). This allows me to not be bound by a fixed number of customer columns. I am also lucky that it is guaranteed I won't have spaces in my customer IDs. But your second formula for handling spaces is fantastic! Thank you!

Comment: I'm looking to do something related to this and came across this answer as part of my Googling. Can you explain the function of the "9^9" in the query function? This isn't something I've encountered before, and bit lost as to what's going on...

Comment: It's a little hack with the QUERY function. It's the header parameter that determines the number of header rows at the top of the data. Eg, with a value of 3, you get the first 3 rows merged into the cell where the query sits. 9^9 is the same as power(9,9) = 387420489 so it's a simple notation to get a large header value. So 387420489 rows of query data will all be merged in the query cell (separated by a space). To see it in action, add 10 sample city names in col A, then put this formula in cell B1: =query(A:A,"",3)   Note what happens as you increase 3.